# Kendo grid MVC number link column sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid on a MVC .cshtml view page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.GetItems>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true
        });
    });
</script>

<table class="table" id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="Quantity">
                Qty
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Quantity.ToString(), "kendo", "Groups", new { ID = item.ID }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It displays the way I want; as a number with a link to a drill down page, but the sorting doesn't work at all.

How can I tell the grid I want the data type to be a number so it can sort it like a number?

(item.Quantity is Int16 from the model, but had to make it a string for the ActionLink to work)

(I'm open to binding the grid differently if I have to (bind to json output from controller and/or use rowTemplate and/or bind to empty div and define columns in JS possibly with template), but not sure at this point if that will matter, seems like a data type issue regardless of binding method???)